# Hi, im struggling to understand O-notation runtime for the if statement in this piece of code

Tags: java, if-statement, matrix, big-o

```
for (int i=0; i<V-1; i++) {
    for (int j=i+1; j<V; j++) {
        if (matrix[i][j]) {
            from[nextedge]=i;
            to[nextedge]=j;
            nextedge++;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to find out the o notation runtime for the if statement and inner for loop but am struggling with how to solve this

Comment: We are going to need to see more code - as is it is constant.

Comment: That piece of code is constant (`O(1)`) because its execution time does not depend on the size of the input, however that is probably inside some amount of loops, looking at those will tell you the actual complexity.

Comment: You aren't showing us a loop here.  The `if` statement would be O(c).  Please show your loop.

Comment: @SethB  sorry, i added the for loops to the code

Comment: the if statement counts as O(1), i.e., a constant operation, __regardless__ of the value of the condition (true or false).

Comment: @C.B. sorry, iv added the loops to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This entire code is `O(V^2)` because the sum of `x` from  `x=1` to `x=V` is `(1/2)V(V+1)`. The inner loop is `O(V)` because the maximum number of iterations it must complete is `V-1` The `if` statement is `O(1)`: there is a constant maximum of steps it completes.

Answer (score 1):

You have two nested `for` loops, each of which depends on the size of `V`. So your total complexity would be O(V<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: The interesting part is `j = i+1` and while it is still a `O(V^2)` the whole point of answering this question is to explain how much does that reduce the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The loop `for(int i = 0; i < V - 1; i++){}` would be O(n) by itself.

You then run `for (int j=i+1; j<V; j++) {}` inside this loop.  Each iteration of `i` this loop runs one less time.  This is V + V-1 + V-2...2+1.  This is V/2. This results in V * V/2 or V * 0.5 V.  Since 0.5 is a constant it is not used, resulting in V * V or O(V<sup>2</sup>)

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html#application  See "Nested loops", item 4.

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html

Comment: Nitpicking: There is no `n` anywhere.

Comment: @DSquare This is Big-O Notation, so I used `N` for Big-O notation.

Comment: `N` is not inherent to the Big-O notation, it's just that when explaining it theoretically it is tradition to say "let N be the size of our input then the Big-O notation would be...". However this is an specific example and the size of the input is `V`.

Comment: To be more clear, the name is important because it may refer to different things. What is the complexity of reading a matrix of size WxH? It's `O(W*H)`. It is not `O(N*N)` or `O(N*M)` it is `O(W*H)` for the defined W and H. You need to be able to identify each "variable" with a dimension of the input, you can't just put the letters you are "used to". They are not meaningless.